# Homotopy of maps to the product topology

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $RP$ denote the real projective plane and let $S$ denote the circle. I recently encountered a question of the form:

Prove every map $f:RP \to S\times S$ is null-homotopic. I know that every map $k:RP \to S$ is null-homotopic. Is it valid to argue that $f: RP \to S\times S$ is a product of maps $g,h:RP\to S, x \mapsto (g(x),h(x))$, and since $g$ and $h$ are nullhomotopic, then $f$ is nullhomotopic?

Comment: Yes, except for the word "composition"

Comment: Great point, I meant to say product. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Have you proved the product of null maps is null?

Comment: LASV--I do not think it is necessary because g and h are nullhomotopic means f is nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your argument is correct.

(I'd do it as follows : let $f : \Bbb RP^2 \to S^1 \times S^1$ be your map. Then the induced map on fundamental groups $\pi_1 f : \Bbb Z/2 \to \Bbb Z^2$ is the zero map, as $\Bbb Z^2$ is torsion-free. Thus, by map lifting lemma, you can lift $f$ to the universal cover to get a map $\widetilde{f} : \Bbb RP^2 \to \Bbb R^2$. As $\Bbb R^2$ is contractible, this is nullhomotopic. Pushdown the homotopy to the base space to conclude that $f$ is nullhomotopic)

Comment: Thank you very much Balarka Sen. Your answer is very helpful, and gave me confidence in my proof. I appreciate the effort you put into your answers.

Comment: @ThinkConnet I'm glad you think this answer is helpful. I posted it to get it off the unanswered queue, really, but figured just a sentence saying "your argument is correct" wouldn't fit as an answer.